# How to pass an object to an overload constructor ? C++

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

How would I go about passing an object (in my case `Snack` object) to an overloaded constructor?

Per the instructions:

> It should have two data members - a `Snack`, and the amount of that `Snac`k that is currently in the slot.

How would I go about passing that snack object to my constructor for `VendSlot`?

```
VendSlot::VendSlot() //default constructor
{
    Snack snackItem;
    numOfSnacks = 5; 
}

VendSlot::VendSlot(Snack snacks, int quantity) //overloaded constructor 
{
    Snack snackObjects = snacks;
    numOfSnacks = quantity;
}
```

And here is my `getSnack()` function: how do I use a get function for an object?

```
int VendSlot::getSnack()
{
    return snacks; //I have no idea how to call the snack object through here?
}
```

**EDIT2** I updated these pieces of code, but are these correct now?

```
    public:
    VendSlot(); //default constructor
    Snack snacks; //instantiate Snack object
    VendSlot(Snack the_snacks, int quantity);
    Snack getSnack(); //return snack
    int getAmount(); //get amount of snacks available
    void decrementAmount(int); //function to decrease storage in vending machine by 1.
   ~VendSlot(); //destructor 

private: 
    Snack snack; //passes snack object
    int numOfSnacks; // number of snacks
{
    Snack snackItem;
    numOfSnacks = 5; 
}

VendSlot::VendSlot(Snack the_snacks, int quantity) //overload constructor 
{
    snacks = the_snacks;
    numOfSnacks = quantity;
    }
int VendSlot::getAmount()
{
    return numOfSnacks;
}
```

Here is the required Main function - there's a lot of other items but I feel like the above is a portion of my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Snack.h"
#include "VendSlot.h"
#include "miniVend.h"


using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    Snack s1("corn chips", 0.75, 200);
    Snack s2("candy bar", 1.25, 300);
    Snack s3("root beer", 2.00, 450);

    VendSlot vs1(s1, 2);
    VendSlot vs2(s2, 1);
    VendSlot vs3(s3, 0);
    VendSlot vs4;  // five bottles of water

    miniVend machine(vs1, vs2, vs3, vs4, 0);



    cout << machine.numEmptySlots() << endl;
    cout << machine.valueOfSnacks() << endl;
    cout << machine.getMoney() << endl;
//  machine.buySnack(1);
    cout << machine.numEmptySlots() << endl;
    cout << machine.valueOfSnacks() << endl;
    cout << machine.getMoney() << endl;

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: from where  passing that snack object to my constructor for VendSlot?? from the default constructor???

Comment: No I was hoping to pass it through the overload constructor, the default constructor is already taking the following       ` Snack snackItem;
 numOfSnacks = 5; `

Comment: We need to see more code - a [mcve] would help a lot. You don't seem to have a `Snack` member variable in your `VendSlot` class, for instance, so `Snack snackObjects = snacks;` is not doing anything useful.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. The `SnackObject` declared within both constructors is pointless; and objects should be passed by reference, not value. Unclear what you're actually asking.

Comment: You have both `Snack snack` and `Snack snacks` in your class. This makes.little sense.

Answer (score 1):

Both your constructors are incorrect in a certain way

```
VendSlot::VendSlot() //default constructor
{
    Snack snackItem; // <-- This is a local variable/object, it is not a member
    numOfSnacks = 5; 
}

VendSlot::VendSlot(Snack snacks, int quantity) //overload constructor 
{
    Snack snackObjects = snacks; // <-- This is a local variable/object, it is not a member
    numOfSnacks = quantity;
}
```

Basically, your `VendSlot` class should look like this:

```
class VendSlot {
    private:
    Snack snacks;
    int numOfSnacks; 
    public :
    VendSlot(): numOfSnacks(0) {
        // write some code to assign default value for snacks
    }
    VendSlot(Snack the_snacks, int quantity) : snacks(the_snacks), numOfSnacks(quantity) {
    }
    Snack getSnack() { return snacks; }
};
```

Note that `getSnack` function should return type `Snack` and not `int`
It is unclear what do you mean by

> how do I use a get function for an object?

Which object are you referring to? The `getSnack` function is supposed to return a copy of member variable `snacks`

**EDIT**

Your edited code still uses local variables inside the constructor and does not initialize the member variable `snacks`. This is where you are going wrong.

You may implement your default constructor this way assuming the following value as default ( as an example )

```
// "root beer", 2.00, 450
VendSlot::VendSlot(): snacks("root beer", 2.00, 450), numOfSnacks(1) {
}
```

Comment: `public:
 VendSlot(); //default constructor
 Snack mySnack; //instantiate Snack object
 VendSlot(Snack the_snacks, int quantity);
 Snack getSnack(); //return snack
 int getAmount(); //get amount of snacks available
 void decrementAmount(int); //function to decrease storage in vending machine by 1.
   ~VendSlot(); //destructor 

private: 
 Snack snack; //passes snack object
 int numOfSnacks; // number of snacks`

Comment: Is the above correct? Then I call it as follows -  `VendSlot::VendSlot() //default constructor
{
 Snack snackItem;
 numOfSnacks = 5; 
}

VendSlot::VendSlot(Snack, int quantity) //overload constructor 
{
 Snack mySnack;
    numOfSnacks = quantity;`

Comment: You should post this piece of code as part of your question.

Comment: @Timk10, how do you call ?

Comment: Your edited code still uses local variables inside the constructor and does not initialize the member variable `snacks`. This is where you are going wrong.

Comment: How do I avoid this?

Comment: Your overloaded constructor looks correct, but your default constructor is wrong. Also, these constructors should be public and not private. As per your latest edit, they are defined in private block and declared in public block, which makes no sense

Comment: We were told we need a getAmount function to retrieve the number of snacks - wouldn't the use of a getAmount be bypassed if I moved to public?

Comment: I asked you to make your constructors public, `getAmount` should also be public, so that it can be called from a function like `main`. Your member variables remain private

Answer (score 0):

First you should instantiate a `Snack` object, then you can pass that into the overloaded constructor of your `VendSlot` class.

```
Snack mySnack;
VendSlot slot(mySnack, 12);
```

This will instantiate an object of type `VendSlot` with the `mySnack` object being passed into the constructor along with `12` being the second argument, quantity.

Answer (score 0):

from another class you can do>

```
VendSlot myVendSlot(mySnack, 5);
```

to get the variable **numOfSnacks** modify getter to

```
int VendSlot::getSnack()
{
    return numOfSnacks; 
}
```

and do:

```
int x = myVendSlot.getSnack();
```

Comment: But the name `getSnack()` suggests that they want to return a snack, not the count of them. Also the OP writes "how do I use a get function for an object?"

Comment: you are right... but why is the method returning an int then?

Comment: for the clarity of the answer i edited my post... thanks @KenY-N